# auto-email information from iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, email, sdk

I'm wondering how easy would it be to implement an auto email function that sends user inputted options.

For example, I have a page where the user enters several options (in this case numbers) into 5 fields, if they then press a 'send order' button and the data is sent in an email to a specified email account?

How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

The iOS email interface in the SDK always shows the user the email before its sent. You can fill it all out, but the user will see the email, and be able to edit it.

To do what you want:
You could create a web site that can accept a POST of the stuff you want to send, and then the web site sends the email.

You could likely add all sorts of code to your app to send the email directly, but it would be a pain, I would guess.

Comment: Doesn't sound as easy as I was hoping, I thought I could possibly parse the data inputted in each of the UITextField and sent that directly (allbeit basically) formatted, but behind the scenes, taking out the part where the user will see the email popover.